# Is there any open source SDK for implementing a KMIP server?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, protocols

Is there any reputable open source SDK for implementing an [OASIS Key Management Interoperability Protocol (KMIP)](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=kmip) server?

Answer (score 2):

Came across this old question. If you are still looking for answers, found the following

1. https://pykmip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html : This one seems to be actively developed.
2. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-kmip4j/index.html : Didn't see much activity here.